# Perl Net::SSH Check if a file exists or not

Tags: perl

I have a requirement to retrieve a file remotely using Net::SSH but my script dies if the file doesn't exist remotely. How can I stop this and get the script just to carry on?

```
eval {  
    my $login_output = $ssh->login($user, $pass);

    foreach $device (keys %{$deviceHashRef})
    {   
                    my $transfer_output = $scpe->scp("$host:/home/portal/runtime/portal_daemon/data/journal/2012.07/refrigeration.case.$device.hourly", '/tmp/poop/input');
    }
};

if($@)
{       
    print Dumper $@;
}
```

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the call in an eval {}, it will catch the die(), and you can process the error.

```
 my $transfer_output = eval { $scpe->scp("$host:/home/portal/runtime/portal_daemon/data/journal/2012.07/refrigeration.case.$device.hourly", '/tmp/poop/input') };
 if ($@) {
   my $err = $@;

   # you can parse the error message out of $err and build an error message
   if ($err =~ /not found/) {
      logger->err('the input file was not found on the remote server');
   }
   else {
     logger->err("file copy encountered a problem: $err");
   }
 }
```